# Response.Redirect is not functioning

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to redirect with this
code:

```
  protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User user = ConnectionClass.LoginUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);

        if (user != null)
        {
            //Store login variables in session
            Session["login"] = user.Username;
            Session["user_type"] = user.Type;

            var userType = (string)Session["user_type"];
            if (userType == "user" && userType == "special_user")
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Customers/Quotation_Customers.aspx");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Login Failed";
        }

    }
```

that is suppose to redirect me to another web page,but the code do not redirect 
at all.

Comment: Is there a specific error or exception you get?

Comment: Switch your `&&` operator to `||`. It will currently always return false.

Comment: No this is a logic error.

Comment: `Response.Redirect` is likely functioning perfectly, but _you're not calling it_.  This is an instance where the debugger comes in handy.

Comment: @DStanley still a beginner in coding.I can't accept your answer at the moment as it says I need to wait for 10 minutes.

Comment: @rainalasa No worries, everyone has to learn.  It's less humbling, though, to find problems like this yourself than for strangers on the internet to point them out :)  The debugger is your friend; learn to embrace it.

Comment: @DStanley yes thanks for the advice.I'll try to make use of the debugger from now on.

Comment: A string cannot be two values at once. Simple logical error here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (userType == "user" && userType == "special_user")
```

This cannot possibly be true.  The string cannot be equal to two different strings.  Did you mean OR (`||`) instead?

Comment: Haha. I saw you put a comment about the logic and then you must have been like, "oh, that's actually the problem!"